# MYSQL interdepedent Query, how do I write this

Tags: mysql

Table one is

```
Posts -> id, comments, threadBelongID
Threads -> id, title
```

Now I want to first find a thread inside of thread using match against, then have it return an id, with that id I want to run a query inside of posts where the id returned from threads is used used to search match against WHERE threadId = (SELECT id FROM threads WHERE match AGAINST()...)

Comment: Could you be more specific on the nature of your threads match?  If you just want to find an id in both, you could do SELECT Threads.id FROM Threads,Posts WHERE Threads.id = Posts.id.  Otherwise, you can just embed SELECTS within each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I imagine you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE threadBelongID IN (SELECT id FROM Threads MATCH(title, content, whatever) AGAINST 'Search term');
```

Have a look at MySQL subqueries here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//subqueries.html